# spring cloud side car hystrix timeout not fire

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, hystrix

I have a simple spring cloud application with side car here is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar

public class SidecarApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SidecarApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The side car call to another service via zuul and I am trying to configure the hystrix timeout without success! here is my configurations:

```
server:
  port: 9085

spring:
  application:
    name: cue

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 100
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout: true
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: true

sidecar:
  port: 8085
  health-uri: http://localhost:8085/health.json
```

in these configurations I expect that if the call to the other service will take more than 100 miliseconds the hystrix will return immediately, but this is not happened(the service hystrix call take 10 seconds)

Am I misconfiguring something?

Note:
The call to the other service is: http://localhost:9085/cma/myinfo1 so the call arrives to the sidecar and cma is the Eureka name of the remote service and it calls the function myinfo1 in the service cma...

Comment: You are using yaml files to configure so your names should follow that convetion. Your hystrix properties are basic properties and not yaml formatted.

Comment: you can both ways, I know it because for example the property: hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled: true really change the behavior of hystrix fallback...

Comment: maybe it relates to this issue: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/354 I am checking it out

Comment: Zuul uses semaphore isolation and hence so does sidecar.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your yaml file is incorrect,you should use standard format.

You can disable hystrix's timeout check:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
```

Or change Zuul's Hystrix isolation strategy to THREAD:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```